# NUnit TestCaseSource how to set parameters from list

Tags: c#, nunit

One of my common `Class` `methods` generates a `list` of `parameters` and I want to set each of them **consistently** as a parameter to my `NUnit` test.

I read some documentation about `TestCaseSource` *attribute* but can't figure out how to implement it.

For example my method return a list with

> "1","2","3","4"

...inside how do I put each of them into my test. Thanks!

Here is my `method` that return a `list`:

```
        public static List<string> TestCombinationsProvider()
    {
        List<string> resultList = new List<string>();
        List<string> parametersList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in ReturnDynamicPararmetersEntityProperties())
        {
            parametersList.Add(item.Name);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < parametersList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < parametersList.Count; j++)
            {
                resultList.Add(parametersList[i] + " AND " + parametersList[j]);
            }
        }

        return resultList;
    }
```

And empty `Nunit` test:

```
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource("")]
    public void Test1()
    {

    }
```

I want to run my test with each row from my list

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: Would really help much if you could show some code and what you expect it to do

Comment: The docs are pretty clear. Instead of returning a `List<string>`, you need to return a list of testcases, e.g. by directly using `IEnumerable<TestCaseData>`, or just `IEnumerable<object>`, where every object itself in an array of your paramaters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCaseSourceAttribute constructor has two overloads if you need to set data from another class you should use this constructor.

```
TestCaseSourceAttribute(Type sourceType, string sourceName);
```

And it looks like this:

```
public class TestData {

    public static IEnumerable<string> TestCombinationsProvider()
    {
        var parametersList = ReturnDynamicPararmetersEntityProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < parametersList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < parametersList.Count; j++)
            {
                yield return  parametersList[i] + " AND " + parametersList[j];
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Tests
{
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestData), nameof(TestData.TestCombinationsProvider))]
    public void Test1(string test)
    {
        Assert.Pass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! That's all I need! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The docs are pretty clear. Instead of returning a `List<string>`, you need to return a list of testcases, e.g. by directly using `IEnumerable<TestCaseData>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestCombinationsProvider()
{
    List<string> resultList = new List<string>();
    List<string> parametersList = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in ReturnDynamicPararmetersEntityProperties())
    {
        parametersList.Add(item.Name);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < parametersList.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < parametersList.Count; j++)
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(parametersList[i] + " AND " + parametersList[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

There are multiple different signatures for that method, e.g. also returning a collection of `object[]`. But I won´t recommend them, as you´re losing much of the things you can do with the `TestCaseData`, e.g. setting each tests `Name` or also its `Description`.

Then decorate your actuall test-method:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(TestCombinationsProvider))]
public void Test1(string p)
{

}
```

EDIT: When your `TestCombinationsProvider`-method is in another class use this instead:

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(TheClass), nameof(TheClass.TestCombinationsProvider))]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One more thing I want to ask. I followed your advise and changed my method. But one more thing left. This method is located in different static class and test falls with "System.Exception : The test case source could not be found." My call is here:
[TestCaseSource(nameof(CommonFunctions.TestCombinationsProvider))]

Comment: @Bohdan Updated my answer